# Unable to copy files as superuser on Amazon EC2 server running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to copy a war file to the `webapps` folder of Apache Tomcat 7 on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu. However, I get the following error

```
cp: cannot create regular file ‘apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps/app-beta.war’: Permission denied
```

I've tried running the command as a root user as well (`sudo su`), and it persists. (ie when I type `whoami` it returns `root`)

At times, while doing `sudo su`, I get the following error :

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx
```

To solve this, I have edited `/etc/hosts` and added `127.0.0.1 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx`
The same command (copying a war file to the `webapps` folder) has worked before, but it doesn't seem to anymore.

I've tried restarting the server, to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the immutable flag of that folder by using the command `lsattr folder/`. 
If the immutable flag(i) is set, even the root user can't make changes to the file/folder.
Remove the immutable flag by using the following command `chattr -R -i folder/`